# Problema para guardar un Form_tag con remote true

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails

Buen día, tengo un problema al guardar los datos de mi form_tag, considero que puede ser un error de sintaxis o desconocimiento ya que soy nuevo con Rails y el desarrollo web, mi problema es que estoy usando mi form_tag de la siguiente manera:`

```
<%= form_tag(controller: "payrolls", action: "actualizar", method: "post", remote: true) do%>
```

Cuando doy el submit me guarda los datos pero tambien me renderiza el parcial de actualizar y yo no quisiera que haga eso, pero si no creo el actualizar.html.erb me tira un error 204 porque no encuentra el templete, cabe destacar que en el action actualizar no hago ningun respond_to, intente con JS pero me marca error.

De antemano agradezco la ayuda que me puedan brindar, saludos.

Aquí esta mi accion actualizar:

```
def actualizar
  payroll_params[:payroll].each do |upd_params|
    params_employeewd= upd_params[:employee_wd_attributes]

    params_payroll = {:employee_id=>upd_params[:employee_id], :week_id=>upd_params[:week_id], :department_id=>upd_params[:department_id], :dias_trabajados=>upd_params[:dias_trabajados],
            :dias_vacaciones=>upd_params[:dias_vacaciones], :faltas=>upd_params[:faltas], :total_percepciones=>upd_params[:total_percepciones], :total_retenciones=>upd_params[:total_retenciones],
            :total_sueldo_bruto=>upd_params[:total_sueldo_bruto], :total_sueldo_neto=>upd_params[:total_sueldo_neto], :sueldo_fiscal=>upd_params[:sueldo_fiscal], :pago_impuesto=>upd_params[:pago_impuesto],
            :pago_eps=>upd_params[:pago_eps], :tipo_pago_fiscal=>upd_params[:tipo_pago_fiscal], :tipo_pago_eps=>upd_params[:tipo_pago_eps]}

    @payroll = Payroll.find(upd_params[:id])
    @payroll.update(params_payroll)

    @employeewd = EmployeeWd.find(upd_params[:employee_wd_attributes][:id])
    @employeewd.update(params_employeewd)

    @employee_wad = EmployeeWad.all.where(payroll_id: upd_params[:id])



    params_employeewad = upd_params[:employee_wad_attributes]
    params_employeewad.each do |employeewad|
      additional = employeewad[:id]
      importe = employeewad[:importe_ads]
      @employee_wad = EmployeeWad.find_by(payroll_id: upd_params[:id],additional_id: additional)
      if importe == '0'
        if @employee_wad 
          @employee_wad.destroy
        end
      else
        if @employee_wad
          @employee_wad.update({:importe_ads=>importe})
        else
          @employee_wad = EmployeeWad.create({:additional_id=>additional,:importe_ads=>importe, :payroll_id=>upd_params[:id]})
        end
      end
    end
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

Ya no me marca error simplemente siempre me redirecciona al templete de actualizar, cosa que no deseo.

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar el controlador? En particular la acción `actualizar`.

Comment: ¿Qué error te muestra cuándo agregas `respond_to` en el controlador?

Comment: @Gerry ya lo coloque, no se si sea correcto lo que estoy haciendo actualmente, pero lo que deseo es que mi tabla se actualice en la base de datos pero sin recargar la vista ya que son demasiados datos y le toma mas de 30 segundos refrescar.